# Late binding and Option Strict

Tags: vb.net, binding, collections, early-binding

I have this problem with late binding: I am creating a grocery list application. I have a class named `Item` which stores the `name`, `price`, `quantity`, and `description` of an item on the grocery list.

I have a module named `ListCollection` which defines a `Collection` of `Item` objects. I have created an `Edit` form which will automatically display the currently selected `ListCollection` item properties, but whenever I attempt to fill the text boxes, it tells me that `Option Strict` disallows late binding.

I COULD take the easy route and disable `Option Strict`, but I'd prefer to figure out what the problem is so I know for future reference.

I shall paste pertinent code here. (Late binding error is in `EditItem.vb`.)

Item.vb code:

```
' Member variables:
Private strName As String

' Constructor
Public Sub New()
    strName = ""

' Name property procedure
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return strName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        strName = value
    End Set
End Property
```

ListCollection.vb code:

```
' Create public variables.
Public g_selectedItem As Integer ' Stores the currently selected collection item.

' Create a collection to hold the information for each entry.
Public listCollection As New Collection

' Create a function to simplify adding an item to the collection.
Public Sub AddName(ByVal name As Item)
    Try
        listCollection.Add(name, name.Name)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

EditItem.vb code:

```
Private Sub EditItem_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Set the fields to the values of the currently selected ListCollection item.
    txtName.Text = ListCollection.listCollection(g_selectedItem).Name.Get ' THIS LINE HAS THE ERROR!
```

I have tried declaring a `String` variable and assigning the `Item` property to that, and I have also tried grabbing the value directly from the `List` item (not using the `Get` function), and neither of these made a difference.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cast the item from "Object" to your type ("EditItem").

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CheatSheetCastingNET.aspx

EDIT:

```
Private Sub EditItem_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' getting the selected item
    Dim selectedItem As Object = ListCollection.listCollection(g_selectedItem)

    ' casting the selected item to required type
    Dim editItem As EditItem = CType(selectedItem, EditItem)

    ' setting value to the textbox
    txtName.Text = editItem.Name
```

I didn't code anything in VB.NET for years, I hope it is all right.

Comment: I am not entirely sure where (or how) I would go about doing this. Would you mind clarifying a bit for me? I read your link, but it's Greek to me.

Comment: Yes! That did indeed work. :) In fact, after a bit of futzing around, it turned out to be even simpler - rather than creating the list as an object and casting it as an Item, I simply creating it as an Item and bypassed the casting altogether. Voila! *And* I learned a little something in the process.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm gald to help you :). This is one of fundamental aspect of OOP. It's called "boxing and unboxing". I recomend you study it.

Comment: Simplified even further, for anybody else who may read this with the same problem:

    "txtName.Text = CType(ListCollection.listCollection(g_selectedItem), Item).Name"

Comment: Now that I see what the problem was, I completely understand it... though  I wish I could find where it was declaring the selected Item in the collection as an Object in the first place!

Comment: Collection is not type safe. You may want to consider changing this to use a List(Of EditItem) and avoid the boxing/casting all together.

Comment: This is not related to boxing.  Boxing deals only with storing references to value-typed values.  e.g. `Dim o As Object = 7`  Since `String` is a reference type, no boxing is required or used.